# How to add limit and offset to sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have this sql query but it does not work:

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
, m.media_link, g_m.member_type 
FROM Group_Members g_m 
LEFT JOIN Users u 
  ON g_m.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN Media m 
  ON u.id = m.user_id 
WHERE g_m.group_id = ? 
AND m.position = ? 
AND m.type = ? 
ORDER BY u.first_name ASC LIMIT ?, 50;
```

This is the error I get

`get memberFound error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', 50' at line 1
GET /group_members?group_id=6&offset=0`

Can anyone help, not sure how to add limit and offset correctly, this query worked without the Limit/offset add...

This is mysql and nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any syntax errors in your SQL.

Use a `setInt` method for the LIMIT question mark.

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.first_name,
  u.last_name,
  m.media_link,
  g_m.member_type
FROM
  Group_Members g_m
  LEFT JOIN Users u ON g_m.user_id = u.id
  LEFT JOIN Media m ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE
  g_m.group_id = ?
  AND m.position = ?
  AND m.type = ?
ORDER BY
  u.first_name ASC
LIMIT
  ?, 50;
```